# Необходимо изменить значение TextView при смене состояния Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-studio

```
package com.example.lab_9;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tvTextLive;
    Button btnStart;
    Button btnExit;
    TextView TextRes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tvTextLive = findViewById(R.id.textLive);
        TextRes = findViewById(R.id.textLiveTwo);
        btnExit = findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnExit.setOnClickListener( this);
        btnStart = findViewById(R.id.btnAfterStart);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

    }





    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onPause()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRestart()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStart()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onResume()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStop()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAfterStart:
                tvTextLive.setText("Приложение запущено");
                break;
            case R.id.btnExit:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Изучаю жизненные циклы. Необходимо изменить текст в textView при переходе в\из жизненный цикл onRestart.
Читал про LifecycleEvent , но, как я понял, этот метод не предусматривает onRestart.

Comment: Так а что у Вас не получается? Вы же с `onCreate` работаете, что с `onRestart` проблемы вызывает?

Comment: В методе onResrart() пишите что то вроде: `myTextView.setText("restart");`и в общем то все.